# Origin of the word "turnpike"

Tags: etymology

Among the definitions on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turnpike) for turnpike are:

> A frame consisting of two bars crossing each other at right angles and turning on a post or pin, to hinder the passage of animals, but admitting a person to pass between the arms; a turnstile.

and

> A gate or bar set across a road to stop carriages, animals, and sometimes people, until a toll is paid; a tollgate.

Is one of these the origin of the word? Did turnpike refer to more of a turnstile device or a single-bar traffic gate, or something else?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/word/turnpike http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/6a9c9698563446e0a02573ea223f0988/disused-rotating-turnstiles-security-gates-de2ga5.jpg

Comment: Or better yet http://www.etymonline.com/word/turnpike

Comment: @mplungjan Quite so. A turnpike is something quite different to a turnstile.

Comment: Why? It’s a turnstile with spikes

Comment: @Clare - is that not the exact same link?

Answer (score 6):

According to the OED, the earliest meaning is of a *spiked barrier fixed in or across a road or passage* as a defensive work; *later writers identify it with the* [cheval de frise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheval_de_frise). The earliest example is from Middle English ca. 1420:

> He made a dyche of grete coste, Pyght with stakys that wolde perysce, With turnepykys, and with many an hers.

The sense of *turnpike* as *a horizontal cross of timber turning on a vertical pin* (a turnstile) is attested from 1545, and the *turnpike* as a barrier across a road used to prevent passage until payment of a toll is from the late 17th century. From there, of course, it came to refer to the road controlled by a turnpike, whence its use in the U.S. for certain toll roads.

Comment: Interesting. Yet "spiked barrier fixed in or across a road or passage " is unfortunately a bit vague, and it is hard to see why it would be described with the word "turn" if it was a static barrier.

Comment: @ColinZwanziger It's a good question, and the OED doesn't go into detail other than to say it is a combining form based on the verb *turn*. Since the configuration and operation of the original *turnpike* is unknown, it might relate to its construction or placement if it involved things arranged around an axis, formed by rotation, or which pivot or twist. There are also the senses of *To reverse the position or posture of* and *to alter the course of… to deflect*, which could apply either to the barrier or to the horse.

Answer (score 4):

As has been mentioned in other answers, the earliest meaning of **turnpike** offered by the *OED* refers to a barricade "as a defence against sudden attack, esp. of men on horseback."

Several of the citations provided seem to suggest that a turnpike in this sense could be *opened* or *closed*, which explains the use of the word "turn."

> My lord hath do brokyn all the passages excep Newhom bryge, weche ys wached and the turne-pyke shette euery nyght.

- **1477**   E. Bedyngfeld in Paston Lett. & Papers (2004) II. 420

> They had no Drawbridge but only a Turnpyke.

- **1644**   in J. Rushworth Hist. Coll.: Third Pt. (1692) II. 739

From the meaning referring to a barrier that can be opened or closed, it makes sense that later meanings referred a toll barrier or a turnstile, whether on roads or waterways.

> **†2.** A horizontal cross of timber turning on a vertical pin, set up to exclude horse-traffic from a foot-way: a turnstile. Obs. **[Attested 1545]**
>
> **†3.** A barrier across a watercourse or stream; a water-gate, allowing the water to flow, but obstructing cattle; also, a lock on a navigable stream. Also turnpike-lock (see Compounds 1). Obs. **[Attested 1623]**
>
> **4.a.** A barrier (orig. of the nature of a turnpike in sense 2, later a gate or gates) placed across a road to stop passage till the toll is paid; a toll-gate. Cf. turnstile n.   Now chiefly Hist. **[Attested 1695]**

Finally, attested in **1748** is a definition that refers to it simply as a shortening of "turnpike road," which has its own separate entry in the *OED*.

> A road on which turnpikes are or were erected for the collection of tolls; hence, a main road or highway, formerly maintained by a toll levied on cattle and wheeled vehicles. Also fig.

The first attestation for this meaning is provided only shortly before the attestation of the ellipsis to simply *turnpike*:

> Turnpike roads were not known in that part of England till some years after.

- **1745**   J. Wesley Wks. (1830) I. 485

**Summary**:

So it seems from examining the entries in the *OED* that a turnpike originally referred to a barrier, likely a movable one that was meant to block intruders, and this term was adopted into the compound form **turnpike road**, meaning a road that contains turnstiles for paying a toll, which was in turn shortened back to **turnpike**, hence the meaning referring to roads with toll passages commonly used in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

A single-bar barrier is the original meaning, referring to medieval verb turnen, meaning "to turn," and the noun pike, meaning "a sharp-tipped weapon.

> - A: The word “turnpike” dates back to 1420, according to the Barnhart Concise Dictionary of Etymology. ***It originally referred to a spiked barrier designed to restrict access to a road. It comes from the Middle English “turnen” (to turn) plus “pike” (a sharp spike).***
> - The Oxford English Dictionary says the spiked barrier was used “as a defense against sudden attack, especially of men on horseback.” ***In the late 17th century, according to the OED, “turnpike” began being used to refer to a barrier on a toll road. By the mid-18th century, the word was used to refer to the road itself.***

(The Grammorphobia)

> - The word itself doesn’t come from turning spikes, but from ***[turn and pike](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-tur2.htm)***, the latter in the old sense of an infantry weapon with a pointed steel or iron head on a long wooden shaft. ***It’s the inclusion of turn here that suggests the pikes were the barrier, which could be turned aside about a vertical pivot to allow access.***

(World Wide Words)